# What topic and equations will characterize the pulling and breaking of a piece of wood

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say hypothetically I pull on a wooden rod from both opposite ends
The rod then breaks in half at the center 
What equations govern this. Is it an engineering problem with things to do with stress and strain and how do I determine at what force does the thing break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ultimate Tensile Strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) is the stress you describe. For something as complicated as wood, it is experimentally measured, and highly variable from sample to sample owing to grain properties and other variables.

If, however, you search on terms like and("tensile strength","quantum mechanics") or "computational nanomechanics" you will find that the numerical quantum mechanical prediction of tensile strength of materials with highly regular structure is becoming quite successful now.

Comment: Understood, any newtonian or classical description of this? What is the mathematics I would need. I am 15 years old and am limited to basic calculus

Comment: @RussellYang Then you would need to look up tensile strength figures of wood. The tensile stress is the force you pull the wood with ("tension") divided by the cross sectional area. Clearly, the force at which the wood will actually fail will be highly variable because wood, even from the same tree, is a highly variable substance.

Comment: What about paper ?

Comment: @RussellYang I should think paper would have a much more repeatable tensile strength. You should either do an experiment or contact the manufacturers. On difficulty in experiment is to ensure that any pulling force is spread evenly over the paper's width.

Comment: @Rodvance that's very helpful, I am actually participating in a competition and characterizing the classic problem of intervening two phone books Whose friction is very large. I want to know the pulling force on both ends of the phone books required to break the whole phone book. Thanks for your help